# Ionic Pro iOS package/build fails - "ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1"

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

Thank you for attempting to help resolve this issue. I'm using the paid Ionic Pro subscription for cloud builds and packaging. All has been fine up until two days ago when **iOS builds suddenly stopped working**.

To be clear, the exact same commit that previously built fine is now not building, with the only visible error message being "**ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1**". The build is still running fine for Android.

I have removed the `cordova-plugin-console` and updated `cordova-ios` as suggested [here](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012555828-Ionic-Pro-Package-iOS-builds-failing-).

I have executed `npm cache clean -f` & `npm install npm -g` as suggested [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-pro-build-failing-with-no-errors-in-log/104882/6).

I have opened a ticket with the Ionic support 24h ago but still no response.

This is the full (very short) build log:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.1.0 (0118d89)
  on Mac Package Runner 2 (dd66aa51)
Using Shell executor...
Running on Ionics-Mac-3.local...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/Users/ionic/builds/dd66aa51/0/project-1'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'xx.xx.xx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Checking out f7b42652 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ fetch-updates
Checking for build process updates...
Running after script...
$ clean-up
Cleaning up files...
Successful clean up
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

And this is my `ionic info`:

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\Andreas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1

System:

    Node : v6.11.0
    npm  : 5.4.2
    OS   : Windows 7
```

I'm starting to feel like there's something strange going on with the Ionic build servers, but I'm very thankful for any pointers and suggestions to try and fix whatever is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem yesterday. But it seems to be working now. You should retry. :)
Alléluia!